# Product of matrices

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have the following matrices A,B,CC,II:

```
A = {{-(k21 + k01), k21, 0}, {k12, -(k12 + k32), k32}, {0, 
    k23, -(k23 + k03)}} // MatrixForm
B = {{0}, {1}, {0}} // MatrixForm
CC = {{1/V1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/V3}} // MatrixForm
II = IdentityMatrix[3] // MatrixForm
```

How can I get the product (^-1 is the inverse):

```
H=CC*(s*II - A)^(-1)*B
```

?

Comment: delete `MatrixForm`, then write `CC.Inverse[(s*II - A)].B` ?

Comment: [this might be useful](http://lmgtfy.com/?s=d&q=matrix+product+mathematica)

Comment: Hello @Alucard your solution works!! Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few well-placed parentheses and the introduction of the operators `Dot` and `Inverse` will solve this problem.

```
(A = {{-(k21 + k01), k21, 0}, {k12, -(k12 + k32), k32}, {0, k23, -(k23 + k03)}}) 
  // MatrixForm
(B = {{0}, {1}, {0}}) // MatrixForm
(CC = {{1/V1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/V3}}) // MatrixForm
(II = IdentityMatrix[3]) // MatrixForm
(H = CC.Inverse[s*II - A].B) // MatrixForm
```

[image: results]

Comment: Excellent solution @m_goldberg.

Answer (score 0):

What is s? Is it a matrix, vector, or scalar? I assume it is a scalar.

And CC is a 2X3 matrix. I am not sure how you want a 2X3 multiplied to a 3X3 matrix. 2X3 can be multiplied to 3Xn through matrix multiplication or tensor product. I will utilize the Tensor Product first.

```
A = {{-(k21 + k01), k21, 0}, {k12, -(k12 + k32), k32}, {0, k23, -(k23 + k03)}};
B = {{0}, {1}, {0}};
CC = {{1/V1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/V3}};
II = IdentityMatrix[3];
MatrixForm[A]
MatrixForm[B]
MatrixForm[CC]
MatrixForm[II]

H = KroneckerProduct[CC, Inverse[(s II - A)].B];
MatrixForm[H]
```

result is:

[image]

and the other solution mentioned:

```
H2 = (CC.Inverse[(s*II - A)]).B
MatrixForm[H2]
```

[image]

using

```
Dimensions[H2]
```

you get

```
(*{2, 1}*)
```

so it is 2X1 matrix.

Comment: Hello @NavidRajil, the result is a 2x1 matrix. See Alucard solution please.

Comment: Since `B` is a vector `H2` must be a vector too. Also your motivation for using `TensorProduct` here is very surprising!

Comment: been working too much with tensor product lately, I can delete it from the answer, but OP did not say that the final answer must be a vector or matrix. and my whole point was that depending on how one multiplies them, one can get the different result. and that 2X3 was the dimensions of the operator on B. sorry on that part.